# Save image from clipboard as .jpg and pass relative link to Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, clipboard, attachment

Using Access 365. I would like help building code to achieve the following please, I’m trying to streamline adding images to a record.

I would like to use VBA that on clicking a button will save an image as a .jpg from the clipboard (put there by User using Snip tool) to a subfolder of the database, then pass a *relative* link to this file to the form. I’d like to be able to attach multiple images’ links to a given record in this manner.

Using the code below (without the AltPrintScreen element) I’ve gotten as far as saving from the clipboard and generating an absolute link, but only as a .bmp. (https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/print-screen-into-image-file.245198/). Grateful for any help getting the rest of the way, or suggestion of an entirely different way of doing it. Cheers!

**Module...**

```
'***********************************************************************************************
'   *
'   * Please leave any Trademarks or Credits in place.
'   *
'   * ACKNOWLEDGEMENT TO CONTRIBUTORS :
'   *       STEPHEN BULLEN, 15 November 1998 - Original PastPicture code
'   *       G HUDSON, 5 April 2010 - Pause Function
'   *       LUTZ GENTKOW, 23 July 2011 - Alt + PrtScrn
'   *       PAUL FRANCIS, 11 April 2013 - Putting all pieces togeather
'   *
'   * DESCRIPTION: Creates a standard Picture object from whatever is on the clipboard.
'   *              This object is then saved to a location on the disc. Please note, this
'   *              can also be assigned to (for example) and Image control on a userform.
'   *
'   * The code requires a reference to the "OLE Automation" type library.
'   *
'   * The code in this module has been derived from a number of sources
'   * discovered on MSDN, Access World Forum, VBForums.
'   *
'   * To use it, just copy this module into your project, then you can use:
'   * SaveClip2Bit("C:\Pics\Sample.bmp")
'   * to save this to a location on the Disc.
'   * (Or)
'   * Set ImageControl.Image = PastePicture
'   * to paste a picture of whatever is on the clipboard into a standard image control.
'   *
'   * PROCEDURES:
'   *   PastePicture  :   The entry point for 'Setting' the Image
'   *   CreatePicture :   Private function to convert a bitmap or metafile handle to an OLE reference
'   *   fnOLEError    :   Get the error text for an OLE error code
'   *   SaveClip2Bit  :   The entry point for 'Saving' the Image, calls for PastePicture
'   *   AltPrintScreen:   Performs the automation of Alt + PrtScrn, for getting the Active Window.
'   *   Pause         :   Makes the program wait, to make sure proper screen capture takes place.
'**************************************************************************************************

Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

'Declare clipboard clear
Public Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

'Declare a UDT to store a GUID for the IPicture OLE Interface
Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

'Declare a UDT to store the bitmap information
Private Type uPicDesc
    Size As Long
    Type As Long
    hPic As Long
    hPal As Long
End Type

'Windows API Function Declarations
#If Win64 = 1 And VBA7 = 1 Then
    
    'Does the clipboard contain a bitmap/metafile?
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long
    
    'Open the clipboard to read
    'Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    
    'Get a pointer to the bitmap/metafile
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long
    
    'Close the clipboard
    'Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    
    'Convert the handle into an OLE IPicture interface.
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long
    
    'Create our own copy of the metafile, so it doesn't get wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
    Declare PtrSafe Function CopyEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" Alias "CopyEnhMetaFileA" (ByVal hemfSrc As Long, ByVal lpszFile As String) As Long
    
    'Create our own copy of the bitmap, so it doesn't get wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
    Declare PtrSafe Function CopyImage Lib "user32" (ByVal handle As Long, ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, ByVal un2 As Long) As Long
    
    'Uses the Keyboard simulation
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

#Else

    'Does the clipboard contain a bitmap/metafile?
    Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long
    
    'Open the clipboard to read
    Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    
    'Get a pointer to the bitmap/metafile
    Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long
    
    'Close the clipboard
    Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    
    'Convert the handle into an OLE IPicture interface.
    Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long
    
    'Create our own copy of the metafile, so it doesn't get wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
    Declare Function CopyEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" Alias "CopyEnhMetaFileA" (ByVal hemfSrc As Long, ByVal lpszFile As String) As Long
    
    'Create our own copy of the bitmap, so it doesn't get wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
    Declare Function CopyImage Lib "user32" (ByVal handle As Long, ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, ByVal un2 As Long) As Long
    
    'Uses the Keyboard simulation
    Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

#End If
  
'The API format types we're interested in
Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
Const IMAGE_BITMAP = 0
Const LR_COPYRETURNORG = &H4

Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C
Private Const VK_MENU = &H12

' Subroutine    : AltPrintScreen
' Purpose       : Capture the Active window, and places on the Clipboard.

Sub AltPrintScreen()
    'keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0
    'keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0
    'keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    'keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
End Sub

' Subroutine    : PastePicture
' Purpose       : Get a Picture object showing whatever's on the clipboard.

Function PastePicture() As IPicture
    'Some pointers
    Dim h As Long, hPtr As Long, hPal As Long, lPicType As Long, hCopy As Long

    'Check if the clipboard contains the required format
    If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_BITMAP) Then
        'Get access to the clipboard
        h = OpenClipboard(0&)
        If h > 0 Then
            'Get a handle to the image data
            hPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP)

            hCopy = CopyImage(hPtr, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_COPYRETURNORG)

            'Release the clipboard to other programs
            h = CloseClipboard
            'If we got a handle to the image, convert it into a Picture object and return it
            If hPtr <> 0 Then Set PastePicture = CreatePicture(hCopy, 0, CF_BITMAP)
        End If
    End If
End Function


' Subroutine    : CreatePicture
' Purpose       : Converts a image (and palette) handle into a Picture object.
' NOTE          : Requires a reference to the "OLE Automation" type library

Private Function CreatePicture(ByVal hPic As Long, ByVal hPal As Long, ByVal lPicType) As IPicture
    ' IPicture requires a reference to "OLE Automation"
    Dim r As Long, uPicInfo As uPicDesc, IID_IDispatch As GUID, IPic As IPicture
    'OLE Picture types
    Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1
    Const PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE = 4
    ' Create the Interface GUID (for the IPicture interface)
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
        .Data2 = &HBF32
        .Data3 = &H101A
        .Data4(0) = &H8B
        .Data4(1) = &HBB
        .Data4(2) = &H0
        .Data4(3) = &HAA
        .Data4(4) = &H0
        .Data4(5) = &H30
        .Data4(6) = &HC
        .Data4(7) = &HAB
    End With
    ' Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.

    With uPicInfo
        .Size = Len(uPicInfo) ' Length of structure.
        .Type = PICTYPE_BITMAP ' Type of Picture
        .hPic = hPic ' Handle to image.
        .hPal = hPal ' Handle to palette (if bitmap).
    End With

    ' Create the Picture object.
    r = OleCreatePictureIndirect(uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic)

    ' If an error occured, show the description
    If r <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Create Picture: " & fnOLEError(r)

    ' Return the new Picture object.
    Set CreatePicture = IPic
End Function


' Subroutine    : fnOLEError
' Purpose       : Gets the message text for standard OLE errors

Private Function fnOLEError(lErrNum As Long) As String
    'OLECreatePictureIndirect return values
    Const E_ABORT = &H80004004
    Const E_ACCESSDENIED = &H80070005
    Const E_FAIL = &H80004005
    Const E_HANDLE = &H80070006
    Const E_INVALIDARG = &H80070057
    Const E_NOINTERFACE = &H80004002
    Const E_NOTIMPL = &H80004001
    Const E_OUTOFMEMORY = &H8007000E
    Const E_POINTER = &H80004003
    Const E_UNEXPECTED = &H8000FFFF
    Const S_OK = &H0

    Select Case lErrNum
        Case E_ABORT
            fnOLEError = " Aborted"
        Case E_ACCESSDENIED
            fnOLEError = " Access Denied"
        Case E_FAIL
            fnOLEError = " General Failure"
        Case E_HANDLE
            fnOLEError = " Bad/Missing Handle"
        Case E_INVALIDARG
            fnOLEError = " Invalid Argument"
        Case E_NOINTERFACE
            fnOLEError = " No Interface"
        Case E_NOTIMPL
            fnOLEError = " Not Implemented"
        Case E_OUTOFMEMORY
            fnOLEError = " Out of Memory"
        Case E_POINTER
            fnOLEError = " Invalid Pointer"
        Case E_UNEXPECTED
            fnOLEError = " Unknown Error"
        Case S_OK
            fnOLEError = " Success!"
    End Select
End Function

' Routine   : SaveClip2Bit
' Purpose   : Saves Picture object to desired location.
' Arguments : Path to save the file

Public Sub SaveClip2Bit(savePath As String)
On Error GoTo errHandler:
    AltPrintScreen
    Pause (2)
    SavePicture PastePicture, savePath
errExit:
        Exit Sub
errHandler:
    Debug.Print "Save Picture: (" & Err.Number & ") - " & Err.Description
    Resume errExit
End Sub

' Routine   : Pause
' Purpose   : Gives a short intreval for proper image capture.
' Arguments : Seconds to wait.

Public Function Pause(NumberOfSeconds As Variant)
On Error GoTo Err_Pause
    Dim PauseTime As Variant, start As Variant
    PauseTime = NumberOfSeconds
    start = Timer
    Do While Timer < start + PauseTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
Exit_Pause:
    Exit Function
Err_Pause:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Pause()"
    Resume Exit_Pause
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a solution that does what I want. I've used four Modules I found on various sites and then created a bit of VBA to pull the tasks together in the background.

- Module 1 is the one I posted in the question above. I bypass the
  AltPrintScreen part of it so it doesn't overwrite the image already in the
  clipboard.
- Module 2 Converts the BMP created by Modules 1 into a JPG.
- Module 3 Scans a folder and populates an unbound listbox with a list
  of the files found there.
- Module 4 is used to make the filepaths in the listbox act as
  hyperlinks to open the images on clicking.

I then created a button on a form that calls the first two Module to create a jpg from the image in the clipboard as follows...

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()

Dim Foldername As String
Dim FileRoot As String
Dim FilePathBMP As String
Dim FilePathJPG As String
Dim FilePathJPG2 As String

' Fist check to see if a unique folder for the open record exists, create if not
Foldername = CurrentProject.Path & "\xrays\" & Format(record_id.Value)
If Len(Dir(Foldername, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir CurrentProject.Path & "\xrays\" & Format(record_id.Value)
End If

On Error GoTo reportErr
   
'The filename will begin with a date\time stamp then pull text from drop down lists the user can pick. This first creates a base filename without filtype extensions.
    FileRoot = CurrentProject.Path & "\xrays\" & Format(record_id.Value) & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmmss") & "_" & Format(Combo14.Value) & "_" & Format(Combo21.Value)
'Creates a BMP and JPG version of the filename
    FilePathBMP = FileRoot & ".bmp"
    FilePathJPG = FileRoot & ".jpg"
'Save a BMP
    SaveClip2Bit FilePathBMP
'Convert to JPG
    WIA_ConvertImage FilePathBMP, FilePathJPG, JPEG, 85
'Delete the BMP
    Kill (FilePathBMP)
    
Exit Sub

reportErr:

MsgBox "No image in Clipboard"
Resume Next

End Sub
```

On the form that will display the file list I've placed an unbound listbox "FileList". The following code calls on Module 3 and is in the OnLoad event of the form...

```
Call ListFiles(CurrentProject.Path & "\xrays\" & Format(record_id.Value), , , Me.FileList)
```

The following code is used to refresh the listbox "FileList". It can be put on an OnClick event of a button or added to the end of the above code to automatically refresh after adding a new image

```
Me.FileList.RowSource = ""
Call ListFiles(CurrentProject.Path & "\xrays\" & Format(record_id.Value), , , Me.FileList)
Me.FileList.Requery
```

Finally I put the following code in the OnDblClick event of the listbox, which calls Module 4...

```
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFile As String

sPath = FileList.Column(0)
' The line below extracts the filename from the full path (everything to the right of the last /)
' sFile = Right(sPath, Len(sPath) - InStrRev(sPath, "\"))
    
GoHyperlink (sPath)
```

**Module 2...**

```
Public Enum wiaFormat
    BMP = 0
    GIF = 1
    JPEG = 2
    PNG = 3
    TIFF = 4
End Enum
 
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : WIA_ConvertImage
' Author    : Daniel Pineault, CARDA Consultants Inc.
' Website   : http://www.cardaconsultants.com
' Purpose   : Convert an image's format using WIA
' Copyright : The following is release as Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International
'             (CC BY-SA 4.0) - https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
' Req'd Refs: Uses Late Binding, so none required
'
' Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)
'             https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630368(v=vs.85).aspx
'
' Input Variables:
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' sInitialImage : Fully qualified path and filename of the original image to resize
' sOutputImage  : Fully qualified path and filename of where to save the new image
' lFormat       : Format to convert the image into
' lQuality      : Quality level to be used for the conversion process (1-100)
'
' Usage:
' ~~~~~~
' Call WIA_ConvertImage("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg", _
'                       "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Chrysanthemum_2.jpg", _
'                       JPEG)
'
' Revision History:
' Rev       Date(yyyy/mm/dd)        Description
' **************************************************************************************
' 1         2017-01-18              Initial Release
' 2         2018-09-20              Updated Copyright
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function WIA_ConvertImage(sInitialImage As String, _
                                 sOutputImage As String, _
                                 lFormat As wiaFormat, _
                                 Optional lQuality As Long = 85) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim oWIA                  As Object    'WIA.ImageFile
    Dim oIP                   As Object    'ImageProcess
    Dim sFormatID             As String
    Dim sExt                  As String
 
    'Convert our Enum over to the proper value used by WIA
    Select Case lFormat
        Case 0
            sFormatID = "{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
            sExt = "BMP"
        Case 1
            sFormatID = "{B96B3CB0-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
            sExt = "GIF"
        Case 2
            sFormatID = "{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
            sExt = "JPEG"
        Case 3
            sFormatID = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
            sExt = "PNG"
        Case 4
            sFormatID = "{B96B3CB1-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
            sExt = "TIFF"
    End Select
 
    If lQuality > 100 Then lQuality = 100
 
    'Should check if the output file already exists and if so,
    'prompt the user to overwrite it or not
 
    Set oWIA = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    Set oIP = CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess")
 
    oIP.Filters.Add oIP.FilterInfos("Convert").FilterID
    oIP.Filters(1).Properties("FormatID") = sFormatID
    oIP.Filters(1).Properties("Quality") = lQuality
 
    oWIA.LoadFile sInitialImage
    Set oWIA = oIP.Apply(oWIA)
    'Overide the specified ext with the appropriate one for the choosen format
    oWIA.SaveFile Left(sOutputImage, InStrRev(sOutputImage, ".")) & LCase(sExt)
    WIA_ConvertImage = True
 
Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not oIP Is Nothing Then Set oIP = Nothing
    If Not oWIA Is Nothing Then Set oWIA = Nothing
    Exit Function
 
Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: WIA_ConvertImage" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
           Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occurred!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

**Module 3...**

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function ListFiles(strPath As String, Optional strFileSpec As String, _
    Optional bIncludeSubfolders As Boolean, Optional lst As ListBox)
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    'Purpose:   List the files in the path.
    'Arguments: strPath = the path to search.
    '           strFileSpec = "*.*" unless you specify differently.
    '           bIncludeSubfolders: If True, returns results from subdirectories of strPath as well.
    '           lst: if you pass in a list box, items are added to it. If not, files are listed to immediate window.
    '               The list box must have its Row Source Type property set to Value List.
    'Method:    FilDir() adds items to a collection, calling itself recursively for subfolders.
    Dim colDirList As New Collection
    Dim varItem As Variant
    
    Call FillDir(colDirList, strPath, strFileSpec, bIncludeSubfolders)
    
    'Add the files to a list box if one was passed in. Otherwise list to the Immediate Window.
    If lst Is Nothing Then
        For Each varItem In colDirList
            Debug.Print varItem
        Next
    Else
        For Each varItem In colDirList
        lst.AddItem varItem
        Next
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

Private Function FillDir(colDirList As Collection, ByVal strFolder As String, strFileSpec As String, _
    bIncludeSubfolders As Boolean)
    'Build up a list of files, and then add add to this list, any additional folders
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim colFolders As New Collection
    Dim vFolderName As Variant

    'Add the files to the folder.
    strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)
    strTemp = Dir(strFolder & strFileSpec)
    Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
        colDirList.Add strFolder & strTemp
        strTemp = Dir
    Loop

    If bIncludeSubfolders Then
        'Build collection of additional subfolders.
        strTemp = Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)
        Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
            If (strTemp <> ".") And (strTemp <> "..") Then
                If (GetAttr(strFolder & strTemp) And vbDirectory) <> 0& Then
                    colFolders.Add strTemp
                End If
            End If
            strTemp = Dir
        Loop
        'Call function recursively for each subfolder.
        For Each vFolderName In colFolders
            Call FillDir(colDirList, strFolder & TrailingSlash(vFolderName), strFileSpec, True)
        Next vFolderName
    End If
End Function

Public Function TrailingSlash(varIn As Variant) As String
    If Len(varIn) > 0& Then
        If Right(varIn, 1&) = "\" Then
            TrailingSlash = varIn
        Else
            TrailingSlash = varIn & "\"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

**Module 4...**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
'Purpose:   Avoid warning and error messages when opening files with FollowHyperlink
'Author:    Allen Browne (allen@allenbrowne.com)
'Release:   28 January 2008
'Usage:     To open MyFile.doc in Word, use:
'               GoHyperlink "MyFile.doc"
'           instead of:
'               FollowHyperlink "MyFile.doc"
'Rationale:
'FollowHyperlink has several problems:
'   a) It errors if a file name contains characters such as #, %, or &.
'   b) It can give unwanted warnings, e.g. on a fileame with "file:///" prefix.
'   c) It yields errors if the link did not open.
'This replacement:
'   a) escapes the problem characters
'   b) prepends the prefix
'   c) returns True if the link opened (with an optional error message if you care.)
'Limitations:
'   - If a file name contains two # characters, it is treated as a hyperlink.
'   - If a file name contains % followed by 2 hex digits, it assumes it is pre-escaped.
'   - File name must include path.
'Documentation:   http://allenbrowne.com/func-GoHyperlink.html

Public Function GoHyperlink(FullFilenameOrLink As Variant) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    'Purpose:   Replacement for FollowHyperlink.
    'Return:    True if the hyperlink opened.
    'Argument:  varIn = the link to open
    Dim strLink As String
    Dim strErrMsg As String
    
    'Skip error, null, or zero-length string.
    If Not IsError(FullFilenameOrLink) Then
        If FullFilenameOrLink <> vbNullString Then
            strLink = PrepHyperlink(FullFilenameOrLink, strErrMsg)
            If strLink <> vbNullString Then
                FollowHyperlink strLink
                'Return True if we got here without error.
                GoHyperlink = True
            End If
            'Display any error message from preparing the link.
            If strErrMsg <> vbNullString Then
                MsgBox strErrMsg, vbExclamation, "PrepHyperlink()"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
Exit_Handler:
    Exit Function
    
Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "GoHyperlink()"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
Public Function PrepHyperlink(varIn As Variant, Optional strErrMsg As String) As Variant
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    'Purpose:   Avoid errors and warnings when opening hyperlinks.
    'Return:    The massaged link/file name.
    'Arguments: varIn     = the link/file name to massage.
    '           strErrMsg = string to append error messages to.
    'Note:      Called by GoHyperlink() above.
    '           Can also be called directly, to prepare hyperlinks.
    Dim strAddress As String        'File name or address
    Dim strDisplay As String        'Display part of hyperlink (if provided)
    Dim strTail As String           'Any remainding part of hyperlink after address
    Dim lngPos1 As Long             'Position of character in string (and next)
    Dim lngPos2 As Long
    Dim bIsHyperlink As Boolean     'Flag if input is a hyperlink (not just a file name.)
    Const strcDelimiter = "#"       'Delimiter character within hyperlinks.
    Const strcEscChar = "%"         'Escape character for hyperlinks.
    Const strcPrefix As String = "file:///" 'Hyperlink type if not supplied.
    
    If Not IsError(varIn) Then
        strAddress = Nz(varIn, vbNullString)
    End If
    
    If strAddress <> vbNullString Then
        'Treat as a hyperlink if there are two or more # characters (other than together, or at the end.)
        lngPos1 = InStr(strAddress, strcDelimiter)
        If (lngPos1 > 0&) And (lngPos1 < Len(strAddress) - 2&) Then
            lngPos2 = InStr(lngPos1 + 1&, strAddress, strcDelimiter)
        End If
        If lngPos2 > lngPos1 + 1& Then
            bIsHyperlink = True
            strTail = Mid$(strAddress, lngPos2 + 1&)
            strDisplay = Left$(strAddress, lngPos1 - 1&)
            strAddress = Mid$(strAddress, lngPos1 + 1&, lngPos2 - lngPos1)
        End If
        
        'Replace any % that is not immediately followed by 2 hex digits (in both display and address.)
        strAddress = EscChar(strAddress, strcEscChar)
        strDisplay = EscChar(strDisplay, strcEscChar)
        'Replace special characters with percent sign and hex value (address only.)
        strAddress = EscHex(strAddress, strcEscChar, "&", """", " ", "#", "<", ">", "|", "*", "?")
        'Replace backslash with forward slash (address only.)
        strAddress = Replace(strAddress, "\", "/")
        'Add prefix if address doesn't have one.
        If Not ((varIn Like "*://*") Or (varIn Like "mailto:*")) Then
            strAddress = strcPrefix & strAddress
        End If
    End If
    
    'Assign return value.
    If strAddress <> vbNullString Then
        If bIsHyperlink Then
            PrepHyperlink = strDisplay & strcDelimiter & strAddress & strcDelimiter & strTail
        Else
            PrepHyperlink = strAddress
        End If
    Else
        PrepHyperlink = Null
    End If
    
Exit_Handler:
    Exit Function
    
Err_Handler:
    strErrMsg = strErrMsg & "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbCrLf
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

Private Function EscChar(ByVal strIn As String, strEscChar As String) As String
    'Purpose:   If the escape character is found in the string,
    '               escape it (unless it is followed by 2 hex digits.)
    'Return:    Fixed up string.
    'Arguments: strIn      = the string to fix up
    '           strEscChar = the single character used for escape sequqnces. (% for hyperlinks.)
    Dim strOut As String            'output string.
    Dim strChar As String           'character being considered.
    Dim strTestHex As String        '4-character string of the form &HFF.
    Dim lngLen As Long             'Length of input string.
    Dim i As Long                   'Loop controller
    Dim bReplace As Boolean         'Flag to replace character.
    
    lngLen = Len(strIn)
    If (lngLen > 0&) And (Len(strEscChar) = 1&) Then
        For i = 1& To lngLen
            bReplace = False
            strChar = Mid(strIn, i, 1&)
            If strChar = strEscChar Then
                strTestHex = "&H" & Mid(strIn, i + 1&, 2&)
                If Len(strTestHex) = 4& Then
                    If Not IsNumeric(strTestHex) Then
                        bReplace = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If bReplace Then
                strOut = strOut & strEscChar & Hex(Asc(strEscChar))
            Else
                strOut = strOut & strChar
            End If
        Next
    End If
    
    If strOut <> vbNullString Then
        EscChar = strOut
    ElseIf lngLen > 0& Then
        EscChar = strIn
    End If
End Function

Private Function EscHex(ByVal strIn As String, strEscChar As String, ParamArray varChars()) As String
    'Purpose:   Replace any characters from the array with the escape character and their hex value.
    'Return:    Fixed up string.
    'Arguments: strIn      = string to fix up.
    '           strEscChar = the single character used for escape sequqnces. (% for hyperlinks.)
    '           varChars() = an array of single-character strings to replace.
    Dim i As Long       'Loop controller

    If (strIn <> vbNullString) And IsArray(varChars) Then
        For i = LBound(varChars) To UBound(varChars)
            strIn = Replace(strIn, varChars(i), strEscChar & Hex(Asc(varChars(i))))
        Next
    End If
    EscHex = strIn
End Function
```

I hope all that helps others!

Comment: that worked great, thanks!

got tired of chart solution
so i just select range, than copy it to clipboard, then do your thing saving it as image locally