Converting Word Shapes to Images to be used in UserForm
I am trying to convert shapes embedded in a Word document into image files so that I can display them in a UserForm. My current approach involves using Microsoft Publisher to save the shapes as image files. Problem is that, It takes a significant amount of time, almost 5seconds per shape.
Here is the code I am using:
Sub ShowImg()

    Dim ImgShape As Shape
    Dim ImgPath As String
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim TempFolderPath As String
    Dim OriginalWidth As Single
    Dim OriginalHeight As Single
    Dim P As Object

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    
    TempFolderPath = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    
    ImgPath = TempFolderPath & "temp_img_2.png"
    
    Set ImgShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes(2)
        With ImgShape
            OriginalWidth = .Width
            OriginalHeight = .Height
                            .Select
        End With
    
    Selection.Copy
    
    Set P = CreateObject("Publisher.Document")
    
    With P.Pages(1).Shapes.Paste(1)
        .LockAspectRatio = False
        .Width = OriginalWidth
        .Height = OriginalHeight
        .SaveAsPicture ImgPath
    End With
    P.Close
    
    Set P = Nothing
    
    'Kill ImgPath

End Sub

Is there a more efficient way to convert Word shapes into images? I need to improvements to reduce the execution time, I have thought about to have a cache of images when it is done first time.

Have you tried to copy the shape to the clipboard and save as an image?

@PeterT Not working

Maybe look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71236417/save-image-from-clipboard-as-jpg-and-pass-relative-link-to-access-form
